# Is there a quicker way to turn on WiFi Hotspot?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, automation, wifi-hotspot

is there a way to automate (or at least reduce the number of steps) to turn on or turn off the WiFi hotspot on my Galaxy 3.

I have to

1. unlock
2. press the menu button
3. press settings
4. press More Settings
5. Tethering and portable hotspot
6. Slide portable hotspot on.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with these 3rd party apps.

Go to "Widgets" in your app drawer. Long-press the "Settings" icon and drag it to your main home screen and the shortcut settings menu for all your settings automatically appears.

Comment: Errm... the "hotspot" setting is not in there on the Galaxy S3.

Comment: Awesome stuff - works great on my Nexus. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Goto Apps (long press an empty spot on your home screen)

Find "Mobile Hotspot" press and hold, drag onto your home screen.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Old question is missing an up-to-date answer: Meanwhile, the solution is built-in to Android and called "Quick Settings".

1. Go to *Settings › Notifications › Quick Settings*
2. Tap the entry to chose/arrange tiles
3. if "WiFi Hotspot" isn't shown on a tile:

   1. tap the <kbd>+</kbd> symbol
   2. scroll to the end of the list
   3. tap the corresponding entry to add (WiFi-Hostpot)
4. optionally: move the tile where you like to have it

Now, toggling the hotspot is as simple as

1. pull-down the notification bar *from the right corner* (this should immediately show Quick Settings)
2. if Quick Settings aren't shown (but your notification area is), tap the top-right corner to switch over
3. tap the hostpot tile

Some ROMs (such as CyanogenMod) even allow you to have the very same stuff "synced" to quick toggles placed on top of the notification area, for even easier access.

Comment: This doesn't work for the Samsung flavor of Android, right?  Maybe you have pure android on a Nexus?

Comment: @JessRiedel I'd never buy a Nex (not unless they give it an SD slot). Not sure about Sammy either. Currently I only have two devices here running Kitkat with CM-flavor.

Comment: I don't see "Quick Settings"

Comment: @AndrewMacFie I can't help that. Especially without more details. If you're eg. running an older Android version, there simply might be no QuickSettings (which were, IIR, introduced around Android 4.4/Kitkat).

Answer (score 0):

Its easy!  Drag down from the top edge to reveal the "Notification Panel." Within the customization options for the Notification Panel there's a mobile hotspot shortcut (on my phone).
[image]

Comment: Looks like nowadays, Mobile Hotspot is available on Quick Settings, so it's not an issue on modern Android anymore. Back then in Android <4.0 though...