# Is there a more efficient way to turn mobile hotspot on / off?

Tags: settings, wifi-hotspot, mobile-data, app-widgets

I'd like to reduce the number of steps needed to turn mobile hotspot on or off. Currently it's unlock, then five taps.

Galaxy Note 4, Android 5.0.1 Lollipop.

I did find [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/is-there-a-quicker-way-to-turn-on-wifi-hotspot), but it's from 2012 and a lot has changed since then probably.

Comment: You could still install Cyanogenmod and the widget mentioned is still aviable in playstore. The fifth answer is still valid too.

Comment: The fifth answer is still valid as well, just create a shortcut no need of third party apps.

Comment: Please don't re-ask a question based on assuming that the answers are now invalid without even checking.

Comment: Apart from that, current one-liner solution: Quick Settings (built-in to Android). Open the notification bar from its right corner, tap the hotspot icon, done. Might need to put it there first, though :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. Drag down from the top edge to reveal the "Notification Panel." Within the customization options for the Notification Panel there's a mobile hotspot shortcut (on my phone).

You can make that shortcut more prominent by adjusting the Notification Panel configuration.